# Xamarin Forms: How to generate a word search puzzle matrix?

Tags: matrix, xamarin.forms, puzzle

I am trying to implement a word search game on my Xamarin forms application. Only words are getting when I call my service. With these words how can I generate a letter matrix?

I need a 10x10 letter matrix like below screenshot:

[image]

The words are hidden inside this matrix-like below screenshot (Stephen, Nicholas, Ambrose, Juan Diego, Xavier, Sylvester I):

[image]

The words can put in any format: the right to left, left to right, top to bottom, bottom to top or in crossway.

Is there any tool for this feature? I need to select the letters as per screenshot 2 for playing this game.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Could you provide information on what you've been trying to no avail?

Comment: @PaulKertscher I am trying to develop a word search game. I need to create a 10x10 letter matrix with my word letters and some other letters.

Comment: there are many projects on github that do something similar that you could study - https://github.com/topics/wordsearch

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Grid**

For example

```
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // I used static source , you could get it from service
        var strList = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" , "D" ,"E" ,"F" ,"G" ,"H" ,"I",..... };


        CreateGame(strList , 10);
    }



    void CreateGame(string[] list , int count)
    {
        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        grid.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        grid.SetBinding(Button.HeightRequestProperty, new Binding("Width", source: grid));



        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < count; j ++)
            {
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });



                var Rowbutton = new Button { Text = list[i* count + j ] };
                Rowbutton.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
                Rowbutton.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
                Rowbutton.SetBinding(Button.HeightRequestProperty,new Binding("Width",source:Rowbutton));
                grid.Children.Add(Rowbutton, j, i);
            }
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        }



        Content = new StackLayout { Children = { grid },HorizontalOptions= LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
    }
}
```

Comment: @ColeX I have multiple words to search in that letter matrix.  So how can I add letters of all words to `strList`. Suppose if I have 6 words to search, the remaining cells should be filled with any other letter in the English alphabet. I need a 10x10 matrix filled with my searchable words in different locations and remaining space in the matrix filled with any other letters.

Please see this [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=188ROWnTNQLiX0Z2oxtlVXoHEJWdkmcVV).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CollectionView with ItemsLayout and Span for it. Check the [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout)

For selection of letters, `SelectionMode` as Multiple can be used.

Xaml code:

```
       <CollectionView
            SelectionMode="Multiple"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LettersCollection}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Span="10" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Hope this could help your requirement.

Comment: Please see this [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=188ROWnTNQLiX0Z2oxtlVXoHEJWdkmcVV).

Comment: You could use custom views and [Touch effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking) and on long press and touch enter events to select the specific cell. You can validate the answer on Touch completed event. Will this be possible for your case?

Set the selection mode to None of CollectionView